# Prometheus & cadvisor / Collect only some metrics with cadvisor

Tags: prometheus, cadvisor

I'm using `cadvisor` to collect metrics on my dockers (running on core os). using `prometheus` as the monitoring server.

I see that prometheus is collecting a lot of metrics which I don't need. I'm trying to find a way to collect only some of the metrics.

didn't find anything in the documentation that allows me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to drop such things at the exporter, but I don't believe cadvisor has support for that. You can use `metric_relabel_configs`:

```
   metric_relabel_configs:
   - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
     regex: 'my_too_large_metric'
     action: drop
```

Prometheus is quite efficient, so metrics should only be dropped if they're causing you performance/resource issues.